# In what programming language is Sublime Text 2 written

Tags: programming-languages, sublimetext

I like Sublime text 2 and how its cross-platform. Do you know in which language is this programm written, or which technologies are used? Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a question a good number of people are interested in (myself included - I was curious if they used Cocoa or not.) Where should such a question be asked, if not on SO?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[From twitter](http://mobile.twitter.com/sublimehq/status/98962887904739329)

> @cwgem Sublime Text 2 is written in C++, with some Objective C for
>   Cocoa integration, and Python for plugins